# GIF loader image doesn't match the background image in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background-image, animated-gif

I can't properly render a loader image on a button after a click in Firefox. As you can see on the 2 images below the loader is properly displayed on Chrome, but it doesn't work as well on Firefox - the loader image doesn't blend into the background and the borders are clearly visible.

Screenshot from Chrome on the left, and from Firefox on the right:

[image: The button in Chrome]
[image: The button in Firefox]

Here's my situation. First I need to support IE 8, which makes all the styling quite problematic. IE 8 not only doesn't support multiple backgrounds, but also the regular button background is a gradient and IE8 doesn't support *linear-gradient* as well. The last obstacle is that the only image format supported by web browsers that can handle animation - GIF - doesn't support multi-level transparency and so is a real hassle to properly blend the loader GIF into an underneath gradient.

My solution is:

- I render the gradient from the image, rather than using *linear-gradient*, so that I have control over any pixel displayed (and I can match the loader image perfectly into the background). The other bonus is IE 8 displays the gradient as well.
- I prepared the loader image myself in a way that it's background is the same gradient image that I use for the button's background (only cut 7px from the top, as the loader is displayed 7px from the button's top). BTW The button's height is *31px* (including the *1px* border), the button background gradient is *1x29px* and the loader image is *16x16px*.
- When displaying the loader image I use CSS' multiple backgrounds, and as a fallback I provide a *background-color* for IE 8 (the loader won't blend perfectly with the background then, but I can live with that if it's only present in IE 8)

Below are the 2 images used: background gradient pattern (which is only *1px* wide) and  the loader. Then the CSS code. You'll notice that I use *Base64* strings for loader images. That's required so that the images load instantly after the click.

[image: Button background gradient]
[image: Loader image]

```
.button-blue,
.button-grey {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 31px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 13.0px !important;       /* IE 8 fallback */
  font-size: 1.08333rem !important;   /* Other browsers */
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.button-grey {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-left: 26px;
  /* IE 8 fallback */
  background-color: #c0e5ea;
  background-image: url(images/arrows/blue-left.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 14px center;
  /* Other browsers *
   * The arrow is irrevelant, as it's displayed only before the button is clicked */
  background: url(images/arrows/blue-left.png) 14px center no-repeat,
              url(images/button-grey-background-regular.png) 0 0 repeat;

/* Displays the loader image after the button is clicked */
.button-grey.button-grey-clicked {
  /* IE 8 fallback */
  background-color: #c0e5ea;
  background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAOf8ALLf5bPf5bTf5rLg5bLg5rbf5rPg5bPg5rTg…NOnb12kRBwoIFU3pNcuBl2rQyDOJY0nH6gO0FBg6YadbMjO0Etg8AGE48Qp8/EYgTDwgAOw==") center 7px no-repeat;
  /* Other browsers */
  background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAOf8ALLf5bPf5bTf5rLg5bLg5rbf5rPg5bPg5rTg…NOnb12kRBwoIFU3pNcuBl2rQyDOJY0nH6gO0FBg6YadbMjO0Etg8AGE48Qp8/EYgTDwgAOw==") center 7px no-repeat,
              url(images/button-grey-background-regular.png) 0 0 repeat;
  color: #c0e5ea;            /* IE 8 fallback */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);   /* Other browsers */
}
```

Does anyone know why the loader image doesn't match the background image on Firefox, when it does render properly on Chrome?

Comment: gifs do support transparency. but it's a boolean "anywhere you see color X, let the background through". FF would let your gradient through just fine if the GIF is set up properly. The problem is that since it's a single-color transparency, you can't feathering/blurring on the contents of the gif, because the bg color used for that feather/blur will be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I formulated that wrongly. GIF do support transparency, but as you said, only a single-color one and that isn't enough to set up a nicely looking loader image. I corrected the sentence in my post.

Comment: Someone here posted a comment (but it looks like he has already deleted it) asking if I tried converting the background images from PNG to GIF. It worked. I don't know why I haven't thought about it myself : ). Anyway thank you very much. You should post it as an answer and I'll accept it.